# Removing inline chunk error script in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, content-security-policy

I have used `create-react-app` to create my ReactJS app. Now, I see that due to some error in loading a chunk while bundling the code, some inline script is generated on the page. Due to this, the content-security policy which does not allow any inline script is violated. Can someone please suggest how to get rid of this inline script? Below is what I see in the generated source in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by changing from true to false the `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK` value in `.env.` There is a little more info in this answer: How to use React without unsafe inline JavaScript/CSS code?

Also consider breaking up into `.env.development and .env.production`: What is the difference between `.env.local and .env.development.local`?